# How can I set global variable in robot framework?

Tags: automation, robotframework

I have written following robot code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  abc

Suite Setup Declare Platform
Suite Setup E2E TestCase Setup

*** Keywords ***
Declare Platform
  ${Platform}=  Set Global Variable  AWS

E2E TestCase Setup
```

I have also tried writing

```
Set Global Variable ${Platform} AWS
```

But I am getting the following error:
Suite setup failed:
Variable '${Platform}' not found.

Comment: Just double checking - Are there at least  2 spaces between `Set Global Variable`, `${platform}` and `AWS`. In the snippet posted here I see only one!

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to [Set global variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) must be the variable name.

Change your `Declare platform` keyword to look like this:

```
Declare Platform
    Set global variable  ${Platform}  AWS
```

---

Note: you also have the problem that you're using `Suite Setup` twice, which robot won't allow. I don't know if that's just a mistake when creating the example or if that's how you have your actual code. If this is your actual code, robot will issue a warning and then will only call the last setup.